# Read .plist file data and record to memory with python

Tags: python, cmd

I have a zip file.  In that zip, I have a plist file, "Restore.plist".  How can I tell python to read
that .plist file and stop when it reaches this part:

```
<key>SupportedProductTypes</key>
<array>
    <string>iPhone3,1</string>
</array>
```

I Want to tell Python to stop at the "SupportedProductTypes" key and record its corresponding string, "iPhone3,1" to memory as a variable, such as "x"
then print x. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

`plistlib` in the Python standard library deals with `.plist` files. Refer to [this PyMOTW article](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/plistlib/) for a quick tutorial.

See also the `ZipFile` class in the `zipfile` module (also in the Python standard library) for reading from ZIP files.

Answer (score 1):

Try with xml :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("keys.xml")
doc = tree.getroot()
sup = doc.getiterator("SupportedProductTypes")

print doc.getiterator("string")[0].text
```

gives:

```
iPhone3,1
```

with this test file called "keys.xml" :

```
<keys>
<key>SupportedProductTypes</key>
<array>
    <string>iPhone3,1</string>
</array>
</keys>
```

Comment: it says AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrib'

Comment: Right. I'm SOOOO sorry, I was again in a hurry.... See edit for solution ! Enjoy.

Comment: yes, copy-paste the test file ... in a file called "keys.xml" !

Comment: okay, how can I do this without the xml test file and on the plist file itself? Also, instead of python printing it, how can I have python save it into memory as a variable that I can call on it later on?

Comment: These are other questions. Try to use ET.parse("Restore.plist") and variable = doc.getiterator("string")[0].text. And please consider accepting an answer.